# How to remove HTML table at form submitting

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have HTML table with dynamically generated contents. A td in the table contains a form. What I want is to remove the table from the page once this form is submitted because another page will be included at form submitting. I am using ajax and php. How can I amend my code below to remove the table once the form is submitted?

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
 function chk(item_id){

     $.ajax({
         type:"post",
         url:"edit_form.php",
         data: { 
             id: item_id, 
             name: $('#name-'+item_id).val() 
         },
         cache:false,
         success: function(html){
             $('#msg').html(html);
         }
     });

     $('#forms').click(function(){
         $('#table').hide();
     });

     return false;
 }
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="msg"></div>
<div id="table">
<table align="center">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th>S/N</th>
            <th>Subject</th>
            <th>Edit</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $i;?></td>
            <td><?php echo $subject;?></td>
            <td>
                <form id="myform">
                   <input type="text" id="name-<?php echo $item_id;?>" hidden name="name" value="<?php echo $item_id;?>" >
                   <button type="submit" id="forms" onclick="return chk(<?php echo $item_id;?>)">Edit</button>
                </form> 
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>    
 </table>
</div>
```

Comment: by "once the form is submitted" you mean after the user clicks submit, OR after the data is saved on the server?

Comment: change button type from 'submit' to 'button'

Comment: @KeyurPadalia how is that relevant?

Comment: because the type submit will submit the form although he is submitting the form in his AJAX call.

Comment: @KeyurPadalia the `return false` from the "chk" function will prevent that.

Comment: @Levi I mean after the user clicks submit

Comment: @Oponjous, see my answer - it will do that.

Comment: Changing button type to 'button' does not remove the table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('#forms').click(function(){
    $('#table').hide();
});
```

At the moment, when the form submits, the above code means you're creating an event handler to listen for the *next time* the button is clicked, which would then hide the table at that time.

To hide it as soon as the form is submitted, then simply remove the event handler part and just write

```
$('#table').hide();
```

by itself within the "chk" function.

N.B. If you don't want it to hide until after the ajax call is completed successfully, then move it inside the "success" function.

Comment: Worked like a charm @ADyson. Your solution removed the table. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

According to your question title:

You can simply add these lines in your `ajax` `success:` :

```
$("#table table").remove();
```

OR

You can set innerHTML of div to `empty`

```
$("#table").html("");
```

I hope this should work.

Answer (score 0):

why do you need a `<form>` tag anyway? a more simple approach which doesn't involve jQuery

HTML

```
<input name="" />
<button id="submit">Submit</button>
```

JS

```
submit.onclick = function(){
   element = document.querySelector('holderClass');
   element.style.display = 'none'; // or any element
   // ...ajax here
}
```

you might need document.querySelector()

Answer (score 0):

```
//In success block you can remove the table by using $('#table').html("");

function chk(item_id){
    $.ajax({
        type:"post",
        url:"edit_form.php",
        data: { 
            id: item_id, 
            name: $('#name-'+item_id).val() 
        },

        cache:false,
        success: function(html){
            $('#msg').html(html);
            $('#table').html("");
         }

        });
    return false;

    }
```